# mysqljs ER_PARSE_ERROR in valid request

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, mysqljs

I'm using `mysqljs` and I want to delete a row in a table with its id:
`class_id` is the id (string).

```js
connection.query(
  `DELETE FROM classes WHERE id = ?`, [class_id], (err, result) => {
      if (err) throw(err);
      resolve();
  }
);
```

Connection:

```
global.connection = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host : config.mysql.hostname,
  user : config.mysql.user,
  password : config.mysql.password,
  database : config.mysql.database,
  charset: 'utf8'
});
```

But I got this error:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM classes WHERE id = 'C2'' at line 1
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\admin\Documents\main\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\admin\Documents\main\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:77:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\admin\Documents\main\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:278:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\admin\Documents\main\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\admin\Documents\main\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\Documents\main\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\Documents\main\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:502:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    --------------------
```

I tried to execute the request manually and it works great.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you atleast show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE classes` output also..

Comment: what version of MySQL are you using, because there's nothing wrong with that query.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE `classes` (
  `id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

Comment: It's MySQL 5.5.39

Comment: indeed like @MarcosCasagrande said that code and table structure also seams to be ok.. Can you show more code how you connect to MySQL in Node.js?

Comment: adding a charset `charset: 'utf8'` to the connection might help?

Comment: Doesn't work either with `utf8`

Comment: then i advice you to drop that `mysqljs` package and try the npm package [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) which seams to be more mature.

Comment: The package I'm using is already `mysql` and not `mysqljs`. I think `mysqljs` is just the name of the node.js library.

Comment: yea might be the case i was confused when you said you are using `mysqljs`.. But then iám out off ideas or possiblities which might case and error of how to solve it... Unless you are trying to connect to a MySQL 8 server.